# What is the CMake equivalent of the GCC -c option?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cmake

For example, if I had a `makefile` that contains this:

```
dynArray.o: dynArray.c dynArray.h type.h 
    gcc -Wall -ansi -c dynArray.c
```

How would I translate that into a `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what your purpose is. If you generate a Unix Makefile, you (implicitly) get all the individual object files as targets (check `make help`). You apparently want to do something more with the object file, why not tell us?

Comment: Our professor gave us a makefile with commands built into it for a project we need to develop (the dynArray files). I am using CLion as my development environment and it uses CMake instead of make so I'm trying to translate the make file over so I can test the code as I write it.

Comment: You don't "translate" Makefiles into CMake. I understand your predicament if you are looking for a quick "make this work" solution, but that's doing CMake a huge disfavor. CMake works at a much higher abstraction level than Makefiles do. (That is why it can use one config file to generate Makefiles, Ninja files, or MSVC projects from it.)

Comment: CMake already does what you are asking for just by asking it to compile a `.c` file.  I am not aware of any generator that doesn't build individual object files from individual source files before deciding what to do with the object files (link them into a shared library, link them into an executable, archive them into a static library, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [CMake's object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_library.html#id4) would do that, that mean compile objects but not archive them like normal library would.

```
add_library(<name> OBJECT <src>...)
```

Comment: It is throwing me this error: CMake Error: Target DynArray has dependency information when it shouldn't. Your cache is probably stale. Please remove the entry

Comment: Update: I deleted my CMakeCache.txt file, then did File->Reload CMake Project and that seemed to sort it out! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's not working. I run it, it says [%100] Build target DynArray but also an error: Error running 'DynArray': File not found: C:\code\c_programming\cs261\assignment_4\cmake-build-debug\DynArray

Comment: @TaylorLiss: Find the point where you are telling CMake to "run" an object library. This is most likely unrelated to the original question -- the piece of Makefile you've shown us doesn't "run" dynArray either, so there has to be some other config item. Perhaps some add_test() or similar. The error message *should* include a hint as to the CMake config location causing the error.

Comment: IMO, you do not need to do this and it just overcomplicates things.  If you are making an executable, just use `add_executable` and list the source files.  CMake's generators will compile the source files one by one and then link the executable from the resulting objects.

Answer (score 1):

Since an object file alone is not the end result of what you are building, I suspect there is more context to the question that is missing.  You are probably building an executable from the objects.  Just use [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_executable.html) to specify your target and the source files that make up the target.  Then use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/target_compile_definitions.html?highlight=target_compile_definitions) to specify the compile options you want while compiling source files for that target.  For example:

```
add_executable(dynArray dynArray.c dynArray.h type.h)
target_compile_definitions(dynArray PRIVATE -Wall -ansi)
```

You can verify that the resulting compile commands are what you expect by using the `Unix Makefiles` generator and passing `VERBOSE=1` to the make command:

```
mkdir build; cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make VERBOSE=1
```

This will cause the generated Makefile to display the full command lines used on every step of the build.